# Creating a custom style/theme in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-styles

I am trying to create a custom style for my app launcher. I have tried various suggestions that fail to produce the desired style.

I am trying to create a style with:

- transparent status bar
- transparent action bar
- menu overflow button in white (3 dots in the top right hand corner)
- shows the wallpaper
- transparent softkeys

[Example of what I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzl9n.jpg)

My minSDKversion=21 and I am extending the AppCompatActivity in my Main Activity.

Current theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar" />
```

Any help with helping me create this style would appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of what you already got or tried and what exactly is not working.

Comment: @jonas.koeritz when i try to extend Activity with android:theme=Theme.Material.Wallpaper i get the wallpaper to show but the overflow menu disappears and the softkeys and statusbar remain black.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own theme inheriting `Theme.Material.Wallpaper`?

Comment: @jonas.koeritz yes i tried that. I extended Activity inheriting Theme.Material.Wallpaper which displayed the wallpaper but the action bars 3 dot overflow button was gone.

Comment: Would you please provide your current Theme in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Transparent Actionbar:

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_yellow</item>
</style>
```

values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_yellow</item>
</style>
```

Now you can use these themes in your AndroidManifest.xml to specify which activities will have a transparent or colored ActionBar:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyTransparentActionbarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent"/>

<activity
        android:name=".MyColoredActionbarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"/>
```

enter image description here enter image description here enter image description here enter image description here enter image description here

Note: in API>=21 to get the Actionbar transparent you need to get the Statusbar transparent too, otherwise will not respect your colour styles and will stay light-grey.

Transparent Statusbar (only works with API>=19):
This one it's pretty simple just use the following code:

```
protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
        if (makeTranslucent) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }
```

But you'll notice a funky result: enter image description here

This happens because when the Statusbar is transparent the layout will use its height. To prevent this we just need to:

SOLUTION ONE:
Add this line android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in your layout view container of whatever you want to be placed bellow the Actionbar:

```
...
    <LinearLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

SOLUTION TWO:
Add a few lines to our previous method:

```
protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
        View v = findViewById(R.id.bellow_actionbar);
        if (v != null) {
            int paddingTop = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT ? MyScreenUtils.getStatusBarHeight(this) : 0;
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
            paddingTop += TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            v.setPadding(0, makeTranslucent ? paddingTop : 0, 0, 0);
        }

        if (makeTranslucent) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }

Where R.id.bellow_actionbar will be the layout container view id of whatever we want to be placed bellow the Actionbar:

...
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bellow_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

enter image description here

So this is it, it think I'm not forgetting something. In this example I didn't use a Toolbar but I think it'll have the same result. This is how I customize my Actionbar:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vg = getActionBarView();
        getWindow().requestFeature(vg != null ? Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR : Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentView());

        if (vg != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(vg, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        }
        setStatusBarTranslucent(true);
    }
```

Note: this is an abstract class that extends ActionBarActivity
Hope it helps!